# Flask web app ValidationError ImportError

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm using `flask-mongoengine==0.7.4` and I'm trying to run "manage.py runserver" from this repo and [this commit](https://github.com/fromzeroedu/flaskbook/tree/step-4).

I have mongo db installed and running, I can run "mongo" and connect to the "test" (default) database and modify it. 
I've also googled and came across [this](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/291) but I do not think I should have to upgrade since "fromzeroedu" didn't have to upgrade.

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskbook/manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from application import create_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskbook/application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 81, in load_module
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskbook/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mongoengine.base import ValidationError
ImportError: cannot import name 'ValidationError'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue related  to it's dependency. If you watch the setup.py of flask_mongoengine-0.7.4 (The version described in fromzeroedu's requirements.txt). It says this package depend on `mongoengine>=0.7.10`.

But check [mongoenigne's v0.11.0 tag](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/releases/tag/v0.11.0). It shows since version 0.11.0, `Errors` in `base` has been migrated into `errors`.

So I think it is enough to make you understand what happened. To fix this problem, you really need to upgrade `flask_mongoengine` or install an old version `mongoengine` below v0.11.0.

So in your requirements.txt, if you're gonna have: "flask-mongoengine==0.7.4"
Then you better also specify this: "mongoengine==0.10.0"
Because mongodb has screwed up their own dependencies!

Comment: Do a "pip freeze" so you can see what packages and versions you've got:
pip freeze
Flask==0.10.1
flask-mongoengine==0.7.4
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
mongoengine==0.13.0
pymongo==3.5.1
six==1.11.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1

"""notice mongoengine==0.13.0 and flask-mongoengine==0.7.4"""" They're not compatible... That's a bad dependency that was causing my "ValidationError" traceback (error).